# Drag & Drop to Reorder items within listbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have a listbox displaying some real estate properties which are objects I have stored in a local database. The listbox is bound to this database using simple data binding. I wanted to implement a drag and drop system to allow the user to rearrange the items accordingly. However, no matter which implementation I try that I have found on the internet, the rearranging simply doesn't work. I have tried atleast 5 different versions and all of them allow me to drag the object, display the ghost adorner, and even show the line where the listboxitem will fall, but after releasing the mouse button the item simply doesn't move. No error, no nothing. Here is my code for my listbox, I was hoping it would be some stupid piece of code preventing this from occuring:

```
<ListBox Height="424" 
        Margin="24,80,0,0" 
        x:Name="listBoxProperties"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource propertySummaryTemplate}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"            
        local:DragDropHelper.IsDragSource="True" local:DragDropHelper.IsDropTarget="True"

        Width="216" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" UseLayoutRounding="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
```

EDIT: I think the problem may be something to do with the fact that the entity database is bound to the listbox, meaning that the position of the item needs to be changed within the database instead of simply the position within the listbox itself. I am fairly new to this sort of coding so please excuse my lack of code vocabulary.

Comment: Couldn't say exactly, but I also think that problem is in binding to database. Are you using any pattern(like MVVM) or all logic is placed in code-behind?
Could you provide code for binding listbox to source data?

Comment: You will need to supply more code, there's not much to go on.  What is the DragDropHelper, is it available for download? I assume you have tested your code against some dummy data to eliminate problems with the database.

Comment: some tests while the app is running: change the order in the database; change the order in the bound collection. what happens? next, get the source for the DragDrop code and put breakpoints in the methods which should be firing..

Comment: The DragDropHelper has code that tries to manipulate the collection the ListBox is bound to in order to make the drop take effect. Something's going wrong in this step and you'll need to debug into the DragDropHelper DropTarget_PreviewDrop or DecideDropTarget to find out why it's not working. Or perhaps it is successfully modifying the collection but you are not seeing changes because it is not an ObservableCollection.

Comment: My listbox is bound to the data like so: listBoxProperties.ItemsSource = entities.Properties.ToList();

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking RandomEngy is correct. I think you need an ObservableCollection with an ICollectionView bound to the ListBox. The collection view allows "altering" the viewed collection without disturbing the original items source.